# Assistance with position: absolute; with a slider

Tags: css

I have a slider, and the slider images themselves need to be set to `position: absolute;` to keep images from loading one below another, but instead right on top of each other. This works great, except that any content below it, instead of staying below it, actually goes on top of the slider. How can I get content to start flowing again AFTER the slider? I can't really set a height since the slider's height changes based on the width of your browser (responsive).

Here's a quick example (no, I don't use inline CSS in real projects):

```
<div>logo and stuff here</div>
<div style="position: absolute;">slider goes here</div>
<div>stuff below the slider (i.e. content)</div>
```

The content in the third div should be below the slider, but it's displayed physically on top of it. I want to restore the flow of the page *after* the absolute positioned div.

EDIT: Here's a sample of the actual slider code (although images replaced).

http://jsfiddle.net/ApxJ4/1/

Comment: Any code to work with?

Comment: @KawineshSK - Added an example of what I mean.

Comment: are you k to use jquery to satisfy your need

Comment: @KawineshSK - Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this

```
<div>logo and stuff here</div>
<div style="position: relative; height : 200px; /* set fixed height here, follow absolute div height */ ">
<div style="position: absolute;">slider goes here</div>
</div>
<div>stuff below the slider (i.e. content)</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not change a thing.

Comment: set height properties value in relative div as absolute div height

Comment: It's responsive, there's no set height, as stated in the question. That's why I'm having so much trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div>logo and stuff here</div>
<div class="outerDiv" style="position:relative"><div class="innerDiv" style="position: absolute;">slider goes here</div></div>
<div>stuff below the slider (i.e. content)</div>
```

JQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ 
$(".outerDiv").css('height',$(".innerDiv").height());
});

$( window ).resize(function(){ 
$(".outerDiv").css('height',$(".innerDiv").height());
});
```

Just Set the Height of the Div Dynamically.Detect the resize and change your content.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kawinesh/L4ZSu/1/)

FOR your Fiddle

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ 
    $(".triggers").css('height',$(".mask ul li").height());
    $(".contentDiv").css('height',$(".triggers").height()+$(".mask li").height());

});

$( window ).resize(function(){ 
    $(".triggers").css('height',$(".mask ul li").height());
    $(".contentDiv").css('height',$(".triggers").height()+$(".mask").height());
});
```

[Fiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Kawinesh/ApxJ4/5/)

Comment: Just makes it worse - the slider is now very small, and the content is still in the same position on top of it.

Comment: @MikeMersereau see the demo i have updated according to your sample this works fine. We cant help you with imagining the probelms you face so update your original code in fiddle and we will try.

Comment: @MikeMersereau i don't know y you are using the Empty list at the top of the image.

Comment: Try clicking on one of the list items (little circles, black when selected and white when not so hard to see). It changes the slider image.

Comment: @MikeMersereau k :) so got what you needed ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48746/discussion-between-kawinesh-sk-and-mike-mersereau)

Comment: I didn't realize you updated answer, thought you just commented so I never checked. I just did now and it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, just had a problem with this... There's a huge space now at the base of the page (a space that's the same height as the slider is, even when the browser is re-sized).